# How can we change table-list title color when we tapped on it in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am beginner in Ios and in my project i have added some labels and image on table-list cell ok they have added so for everything is ok

Here my main requirement is when we tapped on table-list cell labels colors must be change and image need to be change as like below image

for this i have written some code but that's not working pleas help me

### my code:-

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *cells=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cells];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cells];
    }

    strip = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 7, cell.frame.size.height)];
    strip.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:strip];

    TitleLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 7, 130, 35)];
    TitleLbl.text =[Right_Menu_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    TitleLbl.textColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
    TitleLbl.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:TitleLbl];

    img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 7, 35, 35)];
    img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArr1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:img];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   TitleLbl.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    strip.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColr];
    img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rahul.png"];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TitleLbl.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    strip.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rahul.png"];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to create a custom UITableViewCell and then in the delegate functions of UITableView get the instance of CustomTableViewCell and set the Labels textColor.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

CustomTableViewCell *cell =(CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView   cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.TitleLbl.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.strip.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColr];
    cell.img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rahul.png"];
}
```

PS: there are many other work arounds for this...it depends on how do you want to implement the code.

Other way,

//set flag variable as

```
@property (strong ,nonatomic) NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;


    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

      self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
      [tableView reloadData];
      }



    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *cells=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cells];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cells];
    }


    strip = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 7, cell.frame.size.height)];
    strip.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];


    TitleLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 7, 130, 35)];
    TitleLbl.text =[Right_Menu_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    TitleLbl.textColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
    TitleLbl.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

    img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 7, 35, 35)];
    img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArr1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    if(indexPath == selectedIndexPath)
    {
        TitleLbl.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        strip.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColr];
        img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rahul.png"];
    }

    [cell.contentView addSubview:strip];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:TitleLbl];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:img];
    }
```

//This code is not tested.

Comment: is there no solution other than CustomTableViewCell

Comment: if I scroll the table the result will affect

Comment: Other way...you can set some flag variable to know which row is selected and...in the cellForRowAtIndexPath make changes by checking the flag value.
In the UITableViewDelegate Method update the flag and reload the tableview.

Comment: edited answer has some code...its not compiled so may have errors. But it shows the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are referring to the **tableview header**.

You can only set tableview header view to your own custom view using the tableHeaderView property of the tableview. You can set the background color of your custom header view normally.

E.g.

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = myHeaderView;
```

Alternatively, if you want to modify the **section header view**, you can use one of the following delegate methods:

- tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:
- dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:

  and return your custom header view there.

Answer (score 0):

From the code, I can see you hold the reference for properties of last known strip, TitleLbl and img, which will always be the components from last UITableViewCell accessed from

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Since your cell has an orange strip on left side, I would prefer creating a custom UITableViewCell to hold the references.

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic,strong) UIView *strip;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UILabel *titleLbl;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIImageView *imgView;

@end
```

then with a custom cell, your code can be

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        // create and add components
        cell.strip = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 7, cell.frame.size.height)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.strip];

        cell.titleLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 7, 130, 35)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.titleLbl];

        cell.imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 7, 35, 35)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.imgView];
    }

    // modify existing components
    cell.strip.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

    cell.titleLbl.text = [Right_Menu_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.titleLbl.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    cell.titleLbl.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

    cell.imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArr1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    if ([cell isSelected]) {
        // remember to keep the changes for cell in it's selected state
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.titleLbl.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.strip.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rahul.png"];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.titleLbl.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    cell.strip.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rahul.png"];
}
```

also you can override the method in your custom cell

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```